# <td> content pushing other <td> content down

Tags: css

I have a simple table with two td's in one row. But for some reason the content in the right td is pushing everything in the left td down. The right td contains an anchor image, and the left a table and a form. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening and it's driving me insane. Any help appreciated!
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can we see any code of yours?

Comment: Can you put the code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something?

Comment: The image doesn't really help, and frankly, I don't like your depiction of the cat (I must admit it's quite original, though).

Comment: Looks like a vertical-align problem.  Try adding `vertical-align: top` to your `td` elements.

Comment: Unless you have to, don't use <table> for layout. Instead, use <div> with css _float_ rule.

Comment: Vertical-align did it :D Why would contents of a td be pushed down without being aligned to the top? Shouldn't it align to the top by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a couple things.

vertical-align: top could be the culprit

or

the nested items in the first td have a margin or padding that is pushing them down?

Comment: It was vertical-align. I just don't understand why content in the second td would push content in the first down. And it was being pushed down by the same height as the image, no matter what image was being displayed there so the second td contend was the culprit. Thanks!

Comment: They were both probably at vertical-align:bottom; but since the picture was larger it set the height of the td to the same as the picture. On the other side you have vertical-bottom and its not as tall as the image so its on the bottom. To test try putting the image on both sides and see if its equal. If not a css reset might help make things consistent. glad it worked :)